# How can I have two steps with the same name without experiencing an "AmbiguousStep" exception?

Tags: python, testing, bdd, python-behave

**Summary**

In [Python Behave](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) is there a way to avoid exceptions due to step names which you wish to use more than once ?

**What I want**

In using [Python Behave](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) I would like to have two steps with the same name, so in this setup ...

```
./features
  customers.features
  products.features
  ./steps
     customers.py
     products.py
```

I would like to have a feature

```
@when('we implement a test')
def step_impl(context):
    assert True is not False
```

available for use in both `customers.features` and `products.features`.

**What I find happens**

When I try to do that I get an exception  `behave.step_registry.AmbiguousStep` exception thrown when I run the tests. I presumed that steps defined in `customer.features` would only look in `customers.py` and `products.features` would only look in `products.py` but apparently not.

Is there any way of doing this short of just `@when('we implement a test 1')` and `@when('we implement a test 2')`.

**What I've tried**

In investigating this I came across a reference within comments on the Behave Repo to [laying your files out like this](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/master/features/runner.use_stage_implementations.feature) but when I tried doing that behave couldn't find any of the steps.

Just to be clear, as I understand it, the approach suggested in [that comment within the behave repos](https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/master/features/runner.use_stage_implementations.feature) in the context of my example is this ..

```
./features
  ./customers
    customers.features
    ./steps
     customers.py
  ./products
     products.features
     ./steps
     products.py
```

however when I've tried it the tests doesn't find any of the steps.

**The Question**

Is there a way to avoid feature name clashes due to step names which you wish to use more than once ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you rather need the following directory structure:

```
features/
  +-- customers_steps/           # -- Step implementations for customers stage.
  |   +-- foo_steps.py
  +-- products_steps/            # -- Step implementations for stage=products.
  |   +-- foo_steps.py
  +-- customers_environment.py   # -- Environment for customers stage.
  +-- products_environment.py    # -- Environment for stage=products.
  +-- customers.features
  +-- products.features
```

Then run it with stage params:

```
behave --stage=customers
behave --stage=products
```

it looks more clear in the [behave stages](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/new_and_noteworthy_v1.2.5.html?highlight=stage#test-stages)